# PHP SimpleXML - Unable to correctly convert SteamID64 to Steam Name with UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml, steam

I've been to get the UTF8 version of the name that is retrieved by this function, but for some reason it doesn't output it with the correct letters.

**Example Output:**

```
Ã‘Â•qÃÂ…ÃŽÂ¹Ã‘ÂÃ‘Â‚Ã¢Â„Â“Ã‘Â”
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ѕqυιятℓє
```

I've ran character set checks on the file, the string as its being pulled from file_get_contents and as the output of the function, as well as the source XML file. MySQL doesn't get the correct version either.

Also, SimpleXML does support UTF-8.

**sudo file -i debug.txt**

```
debug.txt: txt/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**MySQL Collation**

```
utf8_general_ci
```

**Source XML File Header**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

**This (is in the code twice) -**

```
  $enc = mb_detect_encoding($xml, 'UTF-8', true);
  echo 'Detected encoding '.$enc;
```

**Outputs:**

```
Detected encoding UTF-8
Detected encoding UTF-8
```

I'm not sure where else to check for UTF-8 charset or if that is what I am needing to do in the first place. I'm hoping someone here will know how to get the expected version of the name. Thanks ahead of time.

**TextFile (Log) Output Function:**

```
function log_output($message){
  $file = 'debug.txt';
  $current = file_get_contents($file);
  $current .= $message."\n"; 
  file_put_contents($file, $current);  
}
```

**Source Code:**

```
// Converts SteamID(64) to the users current name on Steam.
        function steamid64_to_name($steamid64) {
          // Get User Profile Data
          $xml = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$steamid64.'/?xml=1');
          $enc = mb_detect_encoding($xml, 'UTF-8', true);
          echo 'Detected encoding '.$enc;
          $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
          if(!empty($xml)) {
            if(isset($xml->steamID)) {
               $username = $xml->steamID;// Example: steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198077095013/?xml=1
            } else { 
              $username = "Username Not Found";
            } 
          } else {
            $username = "User XML Not Found"; // Example: steamcommunity.com/profiles/0/?xml=1
          }
          $enc = mb_detect_encoding($xml, 'UTF-8', true);
          echo 'Detected encoding '.$enc;
          return $username;
        }
```

Comment: how do you output this username?

Comment: Updated the OP to show both MySQL Collation and the function that outputs it to the file that allows me to read it.

Comment: Are you looking at the log file with an editor that knows it's a UTF-8 file?

Comment: I'm looking at the file via a browser (Chrome) which has UTF-8 capabilities, also with FTP via Sublime Text, and MySQL (via Chrome) shows the same name.

Comment: What other information can I provide?

Comment: Which charset Chrome _actually_ used to show your response? Check the network tab in DevTools and inspect the response headers.

Comment: ISO-8859-1. After googling around, "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" fixed it coming from certain domains, but other domains are still on ISO-8859-1. I'm going to guess this has become an Apache problem..

Comment: @Caffeine You can specify charset by `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

What you ask about is less about SimpleXML but more with your output encoding. The output encoding is the data that you send to the browser plus the information about the encoding used with that data (data + meta).

You also commmented, that using Apache HTTPDs':

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

fixed the issue for you. That is is telling the browser you data to send to it is UTF-8 encoded. Previously you told the browser it would be some Latin-*n* something therefore you got these wrong looking characters. Just consider that you need to name the language next to the letter so that the person who receives it understands in which language the letter to read.

Apart from that, there are some general rule of thumbs you should take into account to find problems faster and to not write too much code:

- If you read a string from a `SimpleXMLElement` it will give you the data UTF-8 encoded. Regardless of what the encoding of the original file you created it from was.
- SimpleXML handles most of the re-encodings on it's own, all you need to have is a proper iconv installation which is normally the case (otherwise recommended).
- Be strict with yourself and never guess encodings like you did here with `mb_detect_encoding`. It's technically not possible and instead - if the encoding it unknown - obtain that information from the source, not from the data (it is technically not possible to obtain it from the data, this always remains a guess).
- Last but not least, as this regarding a remote service, you should *always* add a layer of indirection here. The most little thing you'd like to introduce here is caching of remote requests I guess, therefore wrapping it into a class is the first step to do.

Some example for your Steam API acccess:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP SimpleXML - Unable to correctly convert SteamID64 to Steam
 * Name with UTF8
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19507614/367456
 */

$profile = new SteamProfile('76561198027590831');
echo $profile->getUsername(), "\n";
var_dump((string)$profile);

/**
 * Class SteamProfile
 *
 * Converts SteamID(64) to the users current name on Steam.
 */
class SteamProfile
{
    const STEAMAPI_URL_MASK = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/%s/?xml=1';
    const UNKONWN_NAME_MASK = 'User #%s (Username Not Found)';

    private $steamId;
    private $xml;

    public function __construct($steamId)
    {
        $this->steamId = $steamId;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        $xml = $this->getXml($this->steamId);

        return $xml->steamID
            ? (string)$xml->steamID
            : sprintf(self::UNKONWN_NAME_MASK, $this->steamId)
            ;
    }

    private function getXml($steamId)
    {
        if ($this->xml) {
            return $this->xml;
        }

        $url = sprintf(self::STEAMAPI_URL_MASK, $steamId);

        if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file($url)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Unable to load XML from "%s"', $url));
        }

        return $this->xml = $xml;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf("%s (SteamID: %s)", $this->getUsername(), $this->steamId);
    }
}
```

Exemplary output (UTF-8 encoded):

```
ѕqυιятℓє | [A]
string(51) "ѕqυιятℓє | [A] (SteamID: 76561198027590831)"
```

As the example and output shows, there is not need to care too much about encodings so far as Steam provides valid XML and Simplexml is made for valid XML. Use UTF-8 on your website as encoding *or* you need to re-encode data from UTF-8 into your target encoding first.

Also by using a `SteamProfile` object, you can later on replace it with a different implementation. E.g. with one that does delegate the remote requests to a different layer.